# IF loop behavior in c++

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, max

I need to find in an image if a pixel has the maximum value compared to the 8 pixels around it.

I am not sure what is the most optimal way, so my idea is to use the if statement like this:

```
if(pixel > pixel1 && pixel > pixel2 && pixel > pixel3 && ... && pixel> pixel8)
```

My question is the following: if it found that for instance pixel is not bigger than pixel1, will it still check the rest of the statement or since it's only ANDs, it will already discard the instruction and go further?

And if the answer is the first one, that would make it very computationally heavy to check each pixel all the time, can somebody give me a hint as how to approach more efficiently this simple problem?

Comment: You might be looking for `if (pixel > *max_element(&pixel[0], &pixel[7]))`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element

Comment: thanks! sounds more efficient

Comment: Do you really have 18 independent distinct identical variables? If so the problem is much more the data design, than && itself!

Comment: not 18, you must confuse the "l" of "pixel" with "1". and the data is to compare the pixels from the neighboring pixels in an image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called [Short Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

> the second argument is only executed or evaluated if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the expression

---

Since the condition is `&&`, it **will NOT check further** if it gets a `false` in any of the conditions.

Similarly if the  condition were `||`, it would stop checking once it finds a `true`.

---

Btw, I am not absolutely certain of the precedence rules, and because of that I would surround each condition in parentheses just to be safe.

```
if((pixel > pixel1) && (pixel > pixel2) && ...
```

Edit: [Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) rules seem to indicate that the parentheses in this case are unnecessary.

Comment: ah, I do use parentheses anyway, I didn't think to rewrite them for the example. :) thanks for very useful and clear answer!

Comment: his precedence is correct, > takes precedence over &&. Putting in extra parentheses though does make the code easier to understand without adding any extra compiler overhead.

Comment: @CashCow yup, exactly why I added an edit instead of removing the entire thing when I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't check the rest of the statements. C++ "short-circuits" conditional statements, ignoring the second operand to an `&&` if the first is false (and ignoring the second operand to a `||` if the second is true).

Answer (score 1):

There is "short-circuit" in C++ that means when first condition satisfies `if` then the second condition will not checked.

For example if `pixel > pixel1` results `false` the following conditions will be ignored.

I refer you to this ["Short circuit evaluation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 1):

The operators `&&` and `||` are so-called 'short circuit operators' in C++ (and in most other languages as well). This means that evaluation will stop as soon as the result can be determined. For `&&`, this means that evaluation of other terms will stop if one term is `false`, because then the answer is `false`, independent of the other terms. Conversely, for `||` this means that evaluation of other terms will stop if one term is `true`.
See also [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 1):

Think of it not as a series but a grouping of expressions so `&&` has just a left and right side, and is left-side associative.

If the left hand side evaluates to `false` it is guaranteed by the standard not to evaluate what is on the right hand side. The right hand side might even contain an access violation (and often does), e.g. checking if a pointer is non-null on the left side, then dereferencing it on the right.

Your operation is `O(N)` at worst. If you do this once, it is the optimal way, if you are going to do this a lot, you'd be better off finding the max value of your pixels then just checking against that one.

Answer (score 0):

While short circuit evaluation has been explained in other answers, it's worth pointing out that a comparison of two pixels may not be completely trivial.  For example, you may wish to add red, green and blue pixel values after multiplying them by a weighting factor (as the human eye is more sensitive to some colours than others)... in that case, if you don't preserve the overall pixel value inside the object being compared (thereby using more memory both for that value and to somehow track when it's invalidated, + CPU time to check & regenerate it when necessary), then you'll have to perform this redundant calculation during every one of those comparisons.  To avoid this, you might - for example - add a "get_brightness()" function that returns a user-defined type that can be compared efficiently with each of the other pixels.

Comment: Thank you, about those things I know. It was just the general approach that I wasn't sure how to do. Also, in my case I have gray scale images, so only one channel.